# how to read/parse dynamically generated web content?

Tags: dynamic, data-generation

I need to find a way to write a program (in any language) that will connect to a website and read dynamically generated data from the website.

Note that it's *dynamically generated*--it's not enough to get the source html, because the data I'm interested in is generated via javascript that references back-end code. So when i view the webpage source, I can't see the data. (For example, go to google, and do a search. Check the source code on the search results page. Very little of the data your browser is displaying is reflected in the source--most of it is dynamically generated. I need some way to access this data.)

Answer (score 2):

Pick a language and environment that includes an HTML renderer (e.g. .NET and the WebBrowser control). Use the HTML renderer to get the URL and produce an HTML DOM in memory (making sure that scripting is enabled). Read the contents of the HTML DOM after the renderer has done its work.

Example (you'll need to do this inside a `System.Windows.Form` derived class):

```
WebBrowser browser = new WebBrowser();
browser.Navigate("http://www.google.com");
HtmlDocument document = browser.Document;
// extract what you want from the document
```

Answer (score 0):

I used to have a Perl program to access Mapguide.com to get the drive direction from one location to another location. I parsed the returned page and save to database. If the source never change their format, it is OK. the problem is the source format often change, your parser also need change.

Answer (score 0):

A simple thought: if we're talking about AJAX, you can rather look up the urls for the dynamic data. Then you can use the javascript on the page you're talking about to reformat this.

Answer (score 0):

If you have Firefox/greasemonkey making a DOM dumper should be a simple matter.